# How can I have a UICollectionview 1 row and cell vertically and horizontally?

Tags: swift, swift2, uicollectionview, collectionview

When I have my telephone in vertical, perfect I have one cell under other under other (....) but when I put my telephone in horizontal I have this problem:

[image]

So, how can I put a cell per one row when I put my telephone in horizontal?.

Comment: Maybe you have fixed width for cells and so they are behaving differently. If you want same behavior assign width & constraints to cells according to screen bounds and reload them on transitions for portrait and landscape.

Comment: Do you know how can I put CGSize with the size the screen ( like auto layaut) ?

Comment: `func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSizeMake(UIScreen.mainscreen.bounds.width, 350)
}`